# How to make vim’s vimgrep command keep indentations?

Tags: vim

I’m trying to use vim’s quick fix (or local) list to get some information extracted from a file. For example, I want to get all the method names of a python module (the idea was borrowed from pycharm). What I want to get in vim’s “local list” is just something like the following:

```
class Foo:
    def one():
    def two():
    def three():
def bar():
def bazz():
```

To achieve that, I do approximately the following steps:

```
:" OK, the current buffer is being used.
:let file_name = expand('%:p')

:" The heart of the process is one of vim’s grep-like command.
:execute 'lvimgrep /\v^\s*(class|def)/ '.file_name

:" I open the results with the “lopen” command because “llist”
:" doesn’t allow me to use concealing.
:lopen

:" Since I’m working with one file, I don’t need information
:" about file name, line number etc.
:setlocal conceallevel=3
:syntax match NonText /\v^.+col \d+([:]|[|])/ transparent conceal
:" Please note, I‘m still able to jump to a line
:" with the “ll” command.
```

But unfortunately I get:

```
class Foo:
def one():
def two():
def three():
def bar():
def bazz():
```

All the indents are swallowed! The result is quite useless… I can’t differentiate which of the functions belong to a class, which of them are stand-alone.

Please note, the concealing doesn’t have a meaningful influence on the result. If I took away the two last commands (conceal-related), nothing significant would change, only the file name and line/column numbers would be shown but the text in the lines would be still without indents anyway.

So, my questions are:

Is it possible to make `lvimgrep` (or an analogue) keep the lines untouched in order to save indentation? Is there a magic command or option to do that? Or should I program my own implementation of `lvimgrep`?

P.S. I’d like to use vim’s regular expressions. But if it’s impossible, I could switch to the external “grep” command (I’m a linux guy) and use the BRE or ERE syntax as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve done it! But it took more than “half an hour” as I supposed early.

During the research, I found that vim’s local list (and I‘m sure quick fix list too) keeps the indentation of a line when it’s unable to recognize the line as a valid “goto information”, when the line format doesn’t correspond to `errorformat`. (See :help quickfix-valid) So, to get a nice looking list it must be rendered manually. But in order to have the possibility of jumping to the items of a search result, a quickfix or local list must be created as well.

I’ve split the task into two functions: the fist one retrieves the data, the second one shows it.

```
function! s:grep_buffer(pattern)
    let file_name = expand("%")
    let b:grepped = [] |" It will store the search results.
    lexpr! [] |" The local list will give the possibility of jumping.
    for line_number in range(1, line('$'))
        let line_content = getline(line_number)
        if line_content =~ '\V'.a:pattern
            call add(b:grepped, line_content)
            laddexpr file_name.':'.line_number.':'.line_content
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

function! s:show_result()
    if exists('b:grepped')
        let grepped = b:grepped |" After creation a new window it’ll be lost.
        vnew
        call append(0, grepped)
        setlocal buftype=nofile |" Don’t make vim save the content.
        setlocal noswapfile
        setlocal nomodifiable
        nn <silent> <buffer> <CR> :exe line(".").'ll'<CR>
        wincmd l |" Now the old window is on the right.
        hide
    endif
endfunction
```

Of course, a convenient key mapping must be designed. (There is a trailing space in the second line.)

```
command! -nargs=1 GrepBuffer call <SID>grep_buffer(<f-args>)
nn <leader>g :GrepBuffer 
nn <silent> <leader>s :call <SID>show_result()<CR>
```

It’s super convenient! When I want to overview the search results again, I call the `show_result` function which replaces the current window with the search results. I can use all the usual navigation tools to move the cursor through the search results. And all I need to jump to an interesting place is just to hit the enter key!

Thanks for all! The problem is solved, vim is the greatest editor.

Answer (score 6):

No, **currently, it is impossible** to make `lvimgrep` (or even similar commands) keep leading whitespace characters in the quickfix (location) list entries, since space and tab characters are [*unconditionally skipped*](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/adbde3fbedd4a5379ddf0cfc9a6854b52955fd4a/src/quickfix.c#L4478) from the beginning, if the text length is greater than **3**.

The only way to achieve the desired behavior (at least, using `*vimgrep` commands) is to **modify the source code**. For example, you might add an option as demonstrated in the following patch:

```diff
diff --git a/runtime/optwin.vim b/runtime/optwin.vim                                                                                                                                                                            
index 7d3a8804d..caac55cf2 100644
--- a/runtime/optwin.vim
+++ b/runtime/optwin.vim
@@ -1299,6 +1299,7 @@ call <SID>OptionG("ve", &ve)
 call append("$", "eventignore\tlist of autocommand events which are to be ignored")
 call <SID>OptionG("ei", &ei)
 call append("$", "loadplugins\tload plugin scripts when starting up")
+call append("$", "locws\tenables whitespace characters for entries in the location window")
 call <SID>BinOptionG("lpl", &lpl)
 call append("$", "exrc\tenable reading .vimrc/.exrc/.gvimrc in the current directory")
 call <SID>BinOptionG("ex", &ex)
diff --git a/src/option.c b/src/option.c
index aabfc7f53..4ba280806 100644
--- a/src/option.c
+++ b/src/option.c
@@ -1791,6 +1791,9 @@ static struct vimoption options[] =
     {"loadplugins", "lpl",  P_BOOL|P_VI_DEF,
                            (char_u *)&p_lpl, PV_NONE,
                            {(char_u *)TRUE, (char_u *)0L} SCTX_INIT},
+    {"locws",      NULL,   P_BOOL|P_VI_DEF,
+                           (char_u *)&p_locws, PV_NONE,
+                           {(char_u *)FALSE, (char_u *)0L} SCTX_INIT},
     {"luadll",      NULL,   P_STRING|P_EXPAND|P_VI_DEF|P_SECURE,
 #if defined(DYNAMIC_LUA)
                            (char_u *)&p_luadll, PV_NONE,
diff --git a/src/option.h b/src/option.h
index c1a25b342..5e17c459e 100644
--- a/src/option.h
+++ b/src/option.h
@@ -602,6 +602,7 @@ EXTERN char_u       *p_lcs;         // 'listchars'

 EXTERN int     p_lz;           // 'lazyredraw'
 EXTERN int     p_lpl;          // 'loadplugins'
+EXTERN int     p_locws;        // 'locws'
 #if defined(DYNAMIC_LUA)
 EXTERN char_u  *p_luadll;      // 'luadll'
 #endif
diff --git a/src/quickfix.c b/src/quickfix.c
index 136c472e1..8e206ddd7 100644
--- a/src/quickfix.c
+++ b/src/quickfix.c
@@ -4417,8 +4417,9 @@ qf_update_buffer(qf_info_T *qi, qfline_T *old_last)
     static int
 qf_buf_add_line(buf_T *buf, linenr_T lnum, qfline_T *qfp, char_u *dirname)
 {
-    int                len;
-    buf_T      *errbuf;
+    int    len;
+    buf_T *errbuf;
+    long   lval;

     if (qfp->qf_module != NULL)
     {
@@ -4472,10 +4473,12 @@ qf_buf_add_line(buf_T *buf, linenr_T lnum, qfline_T *qfp, char_u *dirname)
     IObuff[len++] = '|';
     IObuff[len++] = ' ';

-    // Remove newlines and leading whitespace from the text.
+    // Remove newlines and leading whitespace from the text,
+    // if the user not enabled whitespaces explicitly via locws option.
     // For an unrecognized line keep the indent, the compiler may
     // mark a word with ^^^^.
-    qf_fmt_text(len > 3 ? skipwhite(qfp->qf_text) : qfp->qf_text,
+    get_option_value((char_u *)"locws", &lval, NULL, 0);
+    qf_fmt_text(len > 3 ? (lval ? qfp->qf_text : skipwhite(qfp->qf_text)) : qfp->qf_text,
            IObuff + len, IOSIZE - len);

     if (ml_append_buf(buf, lnum, IObuff,
```

With `locws` option, you could enable whitespace characters in the quickfix/location entries as follows:

```viml
:set locws
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much! Your solution is great but I suppose it’s too complex for my situation. I’d prefer not to touch vim’s code furthermore I don’t know the c language well. After I had posted the question, I realized that I need the feature only for stand-alone files, not for the file tree. That extremely simplifies the task. I think, `expand()`, `readfile()`, `filter()` and half an hour will solve my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

#### Alternative Option

As an alternative, you could just list out the results via `:#` an `:global`

```
:g/\v^\s*(class|def)/#
```

This will print out the relevant lines with their associated line numbers.

A slightly fancier mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :keeppatterns g/\v^\s*(class|def)/#<cr>:
```

With this mapping you can just type the line number and press enter to jump to a line after executing the mapping.

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :#
:h :keeppatterns
:h :range
```

#### Using Quickfix List

In order to use the quickfix list you will need to "mangle" your indent text with another character, e.g. `>`.

```
command! PyLocations call <SID>py_locations()
function! s:py_locations()
  let lst = []
  let bufnr = bufnr('%')
  let pat = repeat(' ', shiftwidth())
  let Fn = {l -> substitute(matchstr(l, '^\s*'), pat, '▶', 'g') . matchstr(l, '\S.*')}
  keeppatterns g/\v^\s*(class|def)>/call add(lst, {'bufnr': bufnr, 'lnum': line('.'), 'text': call(Fn, [getline('.')])})
  call setqflist(lst, ' ')
  cwindow
endfunction
```

Comment: When I saw your solution I thought that it’s exactly what I want. But the `g` command adds line numbers in any way, independently of the `#` flag. And I still need a jumping tool. So, to process buffer “line by line” turned out to be the simplest way.